# What do the titles on the team confirmation screen mean?

Tags: code-name-steam

After selecting a team and equipment for a mission, the confirmation screen will often display titles below my team like "Born Leader" or "Warrior's Spirit"

What do the titles on the team confirmation screen mean?

[image: Titles on team confirmation screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be abilities of the team you selected. Abilities can be viewed on the character select screen while in unit mode. Only abilities that affect the entire team, (marked with an icon), will be shown during the confirmation screen.

For example, Lion's ability is [Courageous](https://codenamesteam.fandom.com/wiki/Courageous), according to the game wiki (which raises team defense by 20%).

On the [Fire Emblem wiki](https://www.fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Code_Name:_S.T.E.A.M.#Lucina), Lucina has the Born Leader ability, which raises the team's attack and defense.

[image: Top screen: lion's ability]

[image: Bottom screen: character selection]

Comment: Abilities that don't appear on the confirmation screen include "*Push: Move crates or enemies*" (Henry) and "*Break: Destroy crates and certain other obstacles*" (John).